# How to call member function through member function pointer?

Tags: c++

I want to call member-functions through member-function-pointers. The calling function is also a member.

```
class A;

typedef int (A::*memFun)();

class A
{
    int P(){return 1;}
    int Q(){return 2;}
    int R(){return 3;}

    int Z(memFun f1, memFun f2)
    {
        return f1() + f2(); //HERE
    }
public: 
    int run();
};

int A::run()
{
    return Z(P, Q);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << a.run() << endl;
}
```

I am not doing it correctly, and am getting error-

```
main.cpp:15:19: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f1 (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f1) (...)'
         return f1() + f2(); //HERE
```

Please show the correct way to do it.

**EDIT** - there is another error, which is solved by having-

```
return Z(&A::P, &A::Q);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(this->*f1)() + (this->*f2)();
```

Regardless of whether you're calling it from inside the class, you have to explicitly specify the object on which to call (in this case `this`). Also note the **required** parentheses. The following is wrong:

```
this->*f1() + this->*f2()
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that works. I did try `this->*f1() + this->*f2()` after seeing compiler error, but ofcourse it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
(this->*f1)() + (this->*f2)()
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved it. But I had another error, which I hadn't mentioned but @Joachim answered it.

Answer (score 3):

While you don't show it, you most likely have errors when calling `Z` as well.

You need to call the function like this:

```
Z(&A::P, &A::Q)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, for solving the problem which I was just about to ask.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use this

```
(this->*f1)();
```